System Settings wont open. Gnome-control-center wont install
Im on Ubuntu 22.04.4. Today i plugged in an hdmi device and opened system settings to configure my display settings. the Settings window crashed and my PC froze. So, i restarted the PC and now whenever i click the settings icon i get the spinning loading wheel and no menu appears. From advice i saw here i tried
sudo apt install --resintall gnome-control-center

and
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade-full
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
sudo apt purge gnome-control-center
sudo apt install gnome-control-center

When purging and reinstalling it looks like it installs fine but running gnome-control center gives:
(gnome-control-center:5633): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 18:30:42.495: Settings schema 'org.gnome.ControlCenter' is not installed Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

